# What is the CultureInfo for Nigeria currency (Naira) in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net

want to display a number with the Naira sign in front of it but i have been unable to do that.. This is what i have tired

```
<asp:Label ID="num" runat="Server" Text='<%#Eval("Number", "{0:NG}") %>'</asp:Label>
```

Comment: The duplicate is seven years old. On my machine (Windows 10), all specific cultures related to Nigeria (there are eight of them), have `"₦"` as the currency symbol. So the duplicate may not apply. Maybe the asker does not even use a Nigerian culture, or maybe the culture has `UseUserOverride` set to true.

Answer (score 0):

**Try This:**

```
<%# String.Format( new System.Globalization.CultureInfo("en-NG"), "{0:C}", 
Eval("Balance") %>
```

Comment: en-NG is an invalid culture identifier is the error i got

Comment: @Mcbaloo What version of Windows, and what version of .NET Framework? What does this give: `<%# string.Join(", ", System.Globalization.CultureInfo.GetCultures(System.Globalization.CultureTypes.SpecificCultures).Where(x => x.Name.EndsWith("NG"))) %>` What language is your website in?

Comment: The specific culture `"ig-NG"` (i.e. ___Igbo (Nigeria)___) seems to be somewhat canonical. But whether it has `"₦"` or `"N"` as symbol may depend on OS version.